# Forcing newline to print correctly again

Tags: java, regex, newline

I had to export a bunch of strings to a CSV that I opened in excel. The strings contained '\n'  and '\t' which I needed included in the CSV so I did the following before exporting the data:

```
public static String unEscapString(String s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        switch (s.charAt(i))
        {
            case '\n': sb.append("\\n"); break;
            case '\t': sb.append("\\t"); break;
            default: sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The problem is that I am now reimporting the data into Java but I can't figure out how to get the newline and tab to print correctly again. I've tried:

```
s.replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```

but it still ignores the newlines. Help?

EDIT: Example of what i'm trying to do:

Say one string in the CSV is "foo \n bar". When I import it using Java and i'm trying to print the same string to the console but have the newline behave correctly

Comment: Could you provide a sample `s` and the result of the `replace`?

Comment: edited the op with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)'s first argument is a *regular expression*. You have 2 choices. You can use plain old [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like so:

```
s.replace("\\n", "\n");
```

or you can escape the slash for the regex parser (which is stripping the single slash out):

```
s.replaceAll("\\\\n", "\n");
```

or

```
s.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\n"), "\n");
```

I would opt for `replace` since you're not using a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
sb.append("\n");
```

Otherwise, you will get a `'\'` and a `'n'` by using `"\\n"`.

---

But I recommend you to use:

```
sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Here `System.getProperty("line.separator")` gives you platform independent newline in java. Also from Java 7 there's a method that returns the value directly: [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29).

Comment: I believe `unEscapString` works as intended, although it is poorly named. It turns actual newline characters into the text `\n`. (In other words, it escapes a string for the export.) Notice the newline and tab characters in the `case` statements. The problem is when trying to put the actual newline characters back in.

Comment: naming conventions aside, jpmc26 is correct in what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actual newline in the string, it should be \n, not \\n. The way you have it, it is being interpreted as a backslash and then an 'n'.